# How to create threads in a python GUI application?

Tags: python, multithreading, user-interface

What is the most proper way of using threads in a python GUI application, if the application has to read a big file at some point? There will probably be 2 threads, 1 for GUI, 1 for reading the file.
Should I create the threads at the start up of the application, or should I create the "file read" thread when it has to read the file?

Comment: Whichever you're most confident with. Just remember that other threads can't access most GUI libraries. Trying to access a GUI function from another thread will crash the GUI. However you can do it the other way around, the GUI can easily access any data in other threads and use them as long as you make sure to lock the variables etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is quite vague as you should probably specify exactly to which gui library your're referring.

In most GUIs I know however the main design is that only one thread (the main thread) should deal with the GUI and therefore it's important that other threads never directly interact with the user interface. The only thing you're normally allowed to do from a different thread is `post`-ing a message for the main GUI loop.

If for example you need a progress then open the progress window in the main thread, start the reader thread that keeps posting messages as the reading proceeds and then a final message once the procedure is complete. Any interaction with the interface should be done in the main thread when handling these posted (async) messages.

If for example you need to implement also a cancel button then the main thread should just set a variable for the worker thread to notice (for a simple variable assignment no mutex protection is needed in Python because assignment is an atomic operation).

Comment: Do you know how to create a thread on-demand (when needed) in python?

Comment: @alwbtc: Python has the `thread` low-level module or the `threading` higher-level module. Using thread simply requires `thread.start_new_thread(read_function, (filename,))` where `def read_function(filename):...` will be executed in a separate thread. For more complex interactions and if you need mutexes then using `threading` is probably a better path.